# How can i preserve the component state in order to make back button working after router.navigateByUrl

Tags: angular

How can I achieve browser back button working fine when I've a component with dynamic content loaded in, then I navigate out of him using `this.router.navigateByUrl`.

The problem is that component A is a search criteria form and result list, now If i've results populated dynamically and I click on result detail (component B) if I click back button I lost my search result list.

I need sticky component state, prevent destroying the component dom, is it possible in angular2?

Comment: I'm using angular5

Comment: This does not answer your question exactly as stated but it might help: If you are willing not to use the router in this case:
One solution to the parent/child list/detail problem where you want to preserve the state of the parent but not see it when the child is showing, is to make it invisible with the hidden attribute, such as
<parent [hidden]="iAmHiding">
When I have done this, I have not used the router.

Answer (score 1):

So if I get your question right your problem is that you have a list, click upon an item in that list to get to the detail view (which is an own component) and you loose the information of those items, if you navigate back to the list.

> Components shouldn't fetch or save data directly and they certainly shouldn't knowingly present fake data. They should focus on presenting data and delegate data access to a service.

You will need a service that contains the items of your list. Check the official documentation, it's explained nicely there. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#why-services

Comment: I already use services for fetching data and component just for presentation, but I need that the list the component obtained via a service fetch will persist in the browser history (and also the UI with search filters I set). 

See http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/stickymodal/#/people/managers sticky states in angularjs, how to do that in angular2?